# I want to change the + into - minus when related accordion

Tags: jquery

Hi i want to change + into - when square  clicked please see the the js fidddle!

https://jsfiddle.net/vkLhfpxt/

```
$('.work-detail2, .work-detail3').hide();
    $('.work-1').addClass('squar-active')

    $('.work-1').click(function(){
        $('.work-1').addClass('squar-active');
        $('.work-2,.work-3').removeClass('squar-active');
        $('.work-detail1').show(500);
        $('.work-detail2, .work-detail3').hide(500);
    });

    $('.work-2').click(function(){
        $('.work-1,.work-3').removeClass('squar-active');
        $('.work-2').addClass('squar-active');
        $('.work-detail2').show(500);
        $('.work-detail1, .work-detail3').hide(500);
    });

    $('.work-3').click(function(){
        $('.work-1,.work-2').removeClass('squar-active');
        $('.work-3').addClass('squar-active');
        $('.work-detail3').show(500);
        $('.work-detail1, .work-detail2').hide(500);
    });
```

Comment: check http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: Thanks for reply.. but to toggle user needs to click on that elemet twice but.. if user skips to next accordion it should close and + sign should be there.That is the problem

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming there's some HTML happening here within the squares. You could call .innerHTML(); on them:

```
$document.getElementByClassName('squar-active').innerHTML = '-';
```

The "getElementByClassName()" function does just that and grabs any elements with the class of "squar-active". The ".innerHTML" function subsequently changes the HTML inside that element to whatever is defined between the parentheses ('as a string').
And you could use the very same functions to change back and forth between "+" and "-".

Best wishes!

EDIT:

```
$('.work-detail2, .work-detail3').hide();
$('.work-1').addClass('square-active')

$('.work-1').click(function(){
    $('.work-1').addClass('square-active');
    $('.work-2,.work-3').removeClass('square-active');
    $('.work-2, .work3').addClass('square-inactive');
    $('.work-detail1').show(500);
    $('.work-detail2, .work-detail3').hide(500);
});

$('.work-2').click(function(){
    $('.work-1,.work-3').removeClass('square-active');
    $('.work-1, .work-3').addClass('square-inactive');
    $('.work-2').addClass('square-active');
    $('.work-detail2').show(500);
    $('.work-detail1, .work-detail3').hide(500);
});

$('.work-3').click(function(){
    $('.work-1,.work-2').removeClass('square-active');
    $('.work-1, work-2').addClass('square-inactive');
    $('.work-3').addClass('square-active');
    $('.work-detail3').show(500);
    $('.work-detail1, .work-detail2').hide(500);
});

$document.getElementByClassName('square-active').innerHTML = '-';
$document.getElementByClassName('square-inactive').innerHTML = '+';
```

This is how I would rewrite the original script. I'm not the most proficient with jQuery, but I really think that should help.

Comment: Oh thanks i should be little elaborate.. it's kinda toggle when the accordion shown the sign should be - as minimization but when another .square class clicked it should close and shows + sign .. i hope you got it

Comment: Yup. If the '+'s and '-'s in the squares are in the html, the .innerHTML() will change it based on the class. That way, when you click one and it becomes active, the plus will revert to a minus. I would personally make a class 'squar-inactive' so it can be called again on that className with '+', so that it's easier to shift between '+' and '-'.

Comment: I would like to clarify that I did not declare the `.innerHTML` function correctly. I believe that it should be
`.innerHTML = 'some string';`.